# How can I create a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote some function.

```
function createGarage(id) {
  var id = 'data.models.'+id+'.pictures';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'models.json',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(data){},
    success: function(data){
      $.each(id, function(name, value) {
        $('#view').append('<img src="./' + value + '" width="100%" class="foto">');
      });
    }
  });    
}
```

And I got the error: **TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a;**
in section where is each loop. I am thinking the problem is with var id, can I do smething like this? This id I need to access valid data in JSON.
In HTML I call this function like: `onClick="createGarage(g21)`"

```
{
  "name": "kalkulator garaży",
  "version": "1.0",
  "models": {
   "g1": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Garaż dwuspadowy (lewo-prawo) z blachy, podwójny",
      "pictures": {
        "0": "/images/dwuspad/trawa-dwojka.png",
        "1": "/images/dwuspad/cien.png",
        "2": "/images/dwuspad/dach-blacha.png",
        "3": "/images/dwuspad/drzwi-lewy-blacha.png",
        "4": "/images/dwuspad/drzwi-prawy-blacha.png",
        "5": "/images/dwuspad/przod-lewy-blacha.png",
        "6": "/images/dwuspad/przod-prawy-blacha.png",
        "7": "/images/dwuspad/bok-blacha.png"

      }
    },
```

Comment: If you want to loop through the data you got back, then `$.each(data`, not `$.each(id`. Your `id` variable contains a *string*. Voting to clos as typo/non-repro.

Comment: Thats what i am asking, how to pass data to each loop in this case,

Comment: See above: `$.each(data, ...`, rather than `$.each(id, ...`

Comment: yes, but data is results from JSON, i need to put in this foreach loop a data.models.g21.pictures to get pictures links from JSON, how to pass from onClick that i need to access g21 in JSON, i don`t want to create a 100 of ajaxs requests

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us an example of the JSON you get back.

Comment: Your id variable is a string you can't loop .What should `value` look like what should `id` look like?

Comment: data.models.g21.pictures and that gives me a img src from json,

Comment: `$.each(data.models.g21.pictures, function(...`  - is there a reason this needs to be in a string?

Comment: yes ok this works, but how to pass from onClick function ? if i got for example 5 imtes on list, and there is for example onClick="createGarage(g21)" and this start function with data.models.g21.pictures,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
function createGarage(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'models.json',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(data){},
    success: function(data){  
      $.each(data.models[id].pictures, function(i){
        $('#view').append(`<img src=".${data.models[id].pictures[i]}" width="100%" class="foto">`);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Onclick button should be
`<button onClick="createGarage('g1');">Click Me!!!</button>`

You are missing quotes inside `onClick` method where you are passing value.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: works, thx... lets upgrade this, if i got link:

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="g22" onClick="createGarage('g22');">Garaż standardowy</a>

how can i onClick get value straight from id in a tag ?

Comment: Welcome buddy :)

Comment: how to, if i got link: <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="g22" onClick="createGarage('g22');">Garaż standardowy</a> how can i onClick get value straight from id in a tag ?

Comment: I want to write the entire admin panel of my cms in ajax. Therefore, I have a purely architectural approach to this solution. Do I have to write separate javascript functions for each function? For example, I have listened to a list of articles that is one function that will receive an id and execute a POST by POST to a PHP file that will be deleted. And so I have to do for every function in the system? Is there any collective functionality or something similar in the construction of such services?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

`var id = 'data.models.'+id+'.pictures';`

and use

`$.each(data.models[id].pictures, ...`

Comment: gives error: TypeError: data.models[id] is undefined